# C: segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've created this function to read a word. I got segmentation fault and I can't find the problem. Here's what I've done.

```
void LeeCaracter(FILE * fp, char * s)

{

    char c;
    int i = 0;

    c = fgetc(fp);
    while(c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\n')
        c = fgetc(fp);
    while(c!=' ' && c!='\n')
      {
          s[i] = c;
          i++;
          c = fgetc(fp);

      }
    s[i] = '\0'; 
}
```

s is a pointer parameter, as I have to use it later. Is it correct to write it just with one *? Thanks for your help!

*And what about if I wanted to know the character that follows the word(' ' or '\n')? I added this after the while loop:
 "printf("%c",c);"
but it doesn't print anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the 's' has enough space for containing a word with maximum characters in the input file. Then you need to make sure that you check for 'End Of File'. Here is a working version. I hope it works for you as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void LeeCaracter(FILE * fp, char * s)
{
  char c;
  int i = 0;

  c = fgetc(fp);
  if (feof(fp)) return;
  while (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    c = fgetc(fp);
  while (!feof(fp) && (c != ' ' && c != '\n')) {
    s[i++] = c;
    c = fgetc(fp);
  }
  s[i] = '\0'; 

  printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main(void)
{
  char s[128]; /* assuming no word is larger than this size */
  FILE *fp = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");

  while (!feof(fp)) {
    LeeCaracter(fp, s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
while(c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\n')
    c = fgetc(fp);
```

So, at this point, two things that c is not are `' '` and `'\n'`.  Then:

```
while(c!=' ' && c!='\n')
  {
      s[i] = c;
      i++;
  }
```

Since the value of c does not change in the loop, the while condition is always true.  Meaning that pretty quickly, `s[i]` will go out of bounds.  You need to check against the length of s, probably by getting that passed in as a parameter (not to mention, rethink your algorithm a bit -- probably you want to fgetc more inside the loop).

Comment: Ooops, you're right. Thank you! But, anyways, there's still segmentation fault somewhere.

Comment: Where did `s` come from?  Like I said, you should also be bounds checking it in that loop.

Comment: @user1367988 When you reach the end of the file, `fgetc` will always return `EOF` (usually -1) and you again have an infinite loop.

Comment: I declared char * s in another funcion which has FILE * fp as one of the parameters. I'll try to figure it out and post it when I get it. Thanks again!

Comment: Got it, instead of "char * s;" I wrote "s = (char *) malloc (50*sizeof(char*));" and now it's ok.